# Define doctrine as Service Container

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I  want to use doctrine in my bundle. When use this in the class that extends Controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

and if i want to use doctrine in other class that doesn't extend Controller . I know about this , i should define doctrine as service , and i do this:

**php class :**

```
namespace News\VillageNewsBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DoctrineService extends Controller
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }
}
?>
```

**service.yml**

```
services:
    doctrine:
            class:      News\VillageNewsBundle\Services\DoctrineService
            arguments:  - @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
```

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@NewsVillageNewsBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

when do up levels i encounter with this error:

```
ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of News\VillageNewsBundle\Services\DoctrineService given, called in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 402 and defined in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php line 34
```

Answer (score 1):

`doctrine` is already a service, that's why you are getting this error.

Why do you need to wrap doctrine into another service? Doctrine already is a service. You have to declare the other class that need to use doctrine as a service, then you inject the entity manager on that service.

Let's assume you have a `FooBar` class:

```
<?php
namespace News\VillageNewsBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class FooBar
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

You just declare this class as a service and pass the `EntityManager`, like this:

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: News\VillageNewsBundle\Services\FooBar
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to News\VillageNewsBundle\Services\DoctrineService::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2396 and defined in /var/www/Symfony/src/News/VillageNewsBundle/Services/DoctrineService.php line 11
500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException

Comment: if you want to inject the em via the constructor, I updated the answer. Please remember you **must not** name your service *doctrine*.

Comment: i solve my problem by change __Construct to __Constructor but know i don't know how to use it in other class that isn't extends from controller ?!

Comment: You must make the class a service, so you can inject the doctrine service. How is this class called?

Comment: I know about this . i should define functionality in my class and then call services in the controller and then use functions .

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason you get this error is that you define `doctrine` service, which already exists. Just change the name and it should work fine:

**services.yml:**

```
services:
    some_other_name:
            class:      News\VillageNewsBundle\Services\DoctrineService
            arguments:  [@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager]
```

Comment: i do but encounter with fatal error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to News\VillageNewsBundle\Services\DoctrineService::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2396 and defined in /var/www/Symfony/src/News/VillageNewsBundle/Services/DoctrineService.php line 11
500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException

Comment: I edited `services.yml` - check with this configuration